# Using CSV file in python to print column

Tags: python, csv

Im using python to solve a TSP problem. I've managed to sort the TSP but I can't get python to read a specific column on input.

This is the layout of my csv file where 1,2,etc is a CID (Customer ID)
**1,Name,Street addr2,Postcode,X,Y
2,Name,Street_addr2,Pcode,x,y**

I need my program to read the CID on input but print and append the x,y for use in a maths calculation.

I'm new to python so any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
 print "Route Calculator"
cur = (0, 0)
xy = []
route = [0]
n = input("Enter number of destinations to visit:")
a = range(1, n + 1)
for i in range(n):
    x, y = input("Enter co-ordinates as x,y:")
    xy.append((x, y))
```

Sorry for lack of code in earlier post and being vague.  I basically want the x,y input to come from the CSV if thats even possible. Rather than x,y input - customer needs to enter the CID and the program reads the csv file for coords

Thanks again

Comment: do I get it right? you get customer id as input and need to output X and Y coordinates from given CSV?

Comment: Yeah thats right, the code I currently use lets me input the coordinates separated by commas. The tutor wants us to input the CID so the program finds the coordinates.Thanks  print "Route Calculator"
    cur = (0, 0)
    xy = []
    route = [0]
    n = input("Enter number of destinations to visit:")
    a = range(1, n + 1)
    for i in range(n):
        x, y = input("Enter co-ordinates as x,y:")
        xy.append((x, y))

Comment: Please put sample code, properly formatted, in your question (NOT a comment); an example of the desired input & output would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used this properly before I've edited now, thanks for feedback so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample code:

```
import csv

def Cid2xy(csv_file, cid):
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    while True:
        try:
            line = reader.next()
            if line[0] == cid:
                return line[4:6]
        except StopIteration:
            return None
```

CSV file content:

```
1,Name1,Street addr1,Postcode,100,100
2,Name2,Street_addr2,Pcode,200,200
```

test output (note that all values are strings):

```
>> cid.Cid2xy(csv_file, '1')
['100', '100']
```